# Excel formula for repeating sequence

Tags: microsoft-excel

Would like to seek assistance for excel formula for matching asset numbers to names. in a column. for column A and B I used this formula:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(A1),B1,IF(ISBLANK(A2),A1,""))
```

It worked as I wanted. but when attempting to reuse it for column F to B it was unsuccessful.

[image]

If there is a better way to do this than the way I am currently that would be great to know. This is what I would like to achieve in column F:

[image]

Also if you need anymore details please feel free to ask for them.
[picture of the full spread sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PodxB.png)

Comment: As I understand your post, you want to populate column F where column E is not blank with the most recent value from column B that corresponds to a non-blank cell in column A on the same row? Have I understood correctly?

Comment: Not exactly. numbers in column B correspond to the vehicle types in column F and I want to populate Column F with vehicle names to match the numbers in column B .

Comment: So why are you populating column B with 1-3001 in the first place? Also, what is the significance of the TX #?

Comment: The TX# belongs to whoever drove the vehicle it has no significance for this, I am only using it since it shows how many times the vehicle was driven. I populated column B with 1-2024 and 1-3001 because those are the asset numbers for the vehicles in column F. For instance the 2018 Isuzu NPR HD in F2 has the asset number of 1-2024 as seen in A2. and was driven  by #TX 9078 once.

Comment: This is not the full spreadsheet would attaching the full thing help make things more clear?

Comment: I think my comment above still summarises what you want to do. Populate column F with a value from column B from a row above the row you are populating in column F. The row from column B is whichever is the first row above the row on column F that has a non-blank cell in column A.

Comment: I think that would work, how would I go about doing that?

Comment: @Davdgup not relevant to the current question, but why did you decide to remove your question about the index/match with date range? It was interesting, but disappeared before I could even consider an answer.

Comment: @Mobus I can re add it if you would like to take a swing at it. i decided to just brute force code it

Comment: Regarding this question, your method of propagating a value downwards isn't uncommon and with a bit of adjustment should work for column F. My bigger concern this that this feels like an awful lot of duplication. What is the end goal? You might be able to achieve the result much more efficiently with a few lookups and perhaps a pivot table. Also, the fact the your formula in B is interrupted by headers seem unintuitive as well.  I would rather create a new column than runs the formula in C uninterrupted.

Comment: @Mobus to help explain my end goal I have added a larger picture of the spread sheet showing more information. Every time a vehicle gets fuel it is given a TX# and a date of fueling and distance between fueling. My goal is to add asset numbers and vehicle types to each of those fueling sessions so that I can calculate amount of miles each vehicle drove in-between fueling sessions. There are 1,000 vehicles.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `E2`, formula copied down :

```
=IF((A2<>"")+ISNUMBER(C2),LOOKUP(2,1/(LEN(B$2:B2)>6),B$2:B2),"")
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks so much this is a huge help

Comment: I have another example that is exactly like this that I could use some help with.